# How to Inject Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring

In order to programmatically refresh the resource bundle cache, I am using Spring's ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.  I am having trouble injecting it into my bean where I want to invoke the clearCache() method.

I've had to resort to the following:

```
private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
  this.messageSource = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource((DelegatingMessageSource)messageSource).getParentMessageSource();
}
```

This works, but there must be a better way.  The message resource is defined as follows:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
<property name="basenames" >
<list>
   <value>WEB-INF/content/Content</value>
 </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

I don't understand why Spring is injecting a message source of type DelegatingMessageSource.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that autowiring by type will work in this case, as the autowire candidate will most likely be the `ApplicationContext` itself (see [section 3.8.2](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) of the reference documentation). This leads to all those layers you have to dig through to get your original `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

Try passing a reference to the `messageSource` bean via XML configuration instead. Annotating the property with `@Qualifier('messageSource')` should work as well.

Comment: I have already tried wiring the bean via the XML configuration but I get the same results.  I haven't tried @Qualifier yet.  I'll give that a go. Thanks.

Comment: Autowiring by name, which is @Qualifier's fallback method, will not help in that case, either. Using the <qualifier> element with your MessageSource definition (http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) might do the trick.

Comment: Alternatively, make your MessageSource client ApplicationContextAware and access the 'messageSource' bean programatically.

Comment: As springify pointed out, if you have an @autowired MessageSource, then Spring will always give you a reference to the application context's own internal MessageSource, which delegates to any others it may have found. 

If you don't want this, then remove the @autowired annotation completely, and manually inject your MessageSource bean. Don't mess about with @Qualifier or the like, it doesn't need to be that complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You usually get the DelegatingMessageSource injected when Spring can't find "messageSource" defined.  Are you sure you're defining it properly or that it's visible where necessary?  I think the problem here is how the XML configuration has been setup.

I had a similar situation with Spring Web Flow and the form action stuff.  In my XML configuration the "messageSource" wasn't visible and causing the DelegatingMessageSource to be injected.  I placed the "messageSource" bean definition into the webflow configuration and then everything worked and I stopped getting the DelegationMessageSource object.  However, this is an ugly fix since now I have "messageSource" defined in two places.

Anyway, this problem only started after I switched to Spring 2.5.6.  I'm using Webflow 1.  Once I have a chance I will try and update to Webflow 2 and see what happens.  Maybe that will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to define the method as:

```
public void setMessageSource(ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSoure) {
    this.messageSoure = messageSoure;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that what I first did, but that failed on initialization with an error about not finding a bean of type ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run it through `messageSource` in your controller, you get NOTHING, empty string.  And if you look closely, you will find that you have a `DelegatingMessageSource` in your messageSource property, with an empty parent source, which means it is EMPTY, i.e. always returns blank and this exception occurs in controller

```
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource incompatible with org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource
```

[Read more..](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=950)