# Programmatically refresh the spring mvc resource bundle

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resourcebundle

ResourceBundleMessageSource messages are configured in Spring's configuration file as

```
<bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
  p:basenames="WEB-INF/strings/appstrings" />
```

Whenever I changed any message in that properties file I have to restart server.

I want to read these updated messages programatically in my application without restarting server.

How can I read these messages programatically in one of my `@Controller` while running application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your ResourceBundle property in applicationContext.xml file like:

```
<!-- Message Source for appstrings -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/strings/appstrings" />

</bean>
```

In you Java class/controller auto-wire it as:

private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

```
  @Autowired
  public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
    this.messageSource = (ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource) ((DelegatingMessageSource) messageSource).getParentMessageSource();
  }
```

Then call clearCache() in any function in that class/controller.

```
messageSource.clearCache();
```

I got this exception in controller

```
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource incompatible with org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource
```

When you try to run it through messageSource in your controller, you get NOTHING, empty string.  And if you look closely, you will find that you have a DelegatingMessageSource in your messageSource property, with an empty parent source, which means it is EMPTY, i.e. always returns blank.

Here’s the solution for this little challenge: move your messageSource definition from spring-servlet.xml to applicationContext.xml!

[Read more..](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=950)

Answer (score 3):

There is a ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html ) in spring that should do what you want.

You can find more info here on stackoverflow:

- [How to Inject Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728455/how-to-inject-spring-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)
- [How to Inject Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728455/how-to-inject-spring-reloadableresourcebundlemessagesource)